# Is there a way to see if anyone has clicked a div with a certain class?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to find a way to automate this very simple question and it's been driving me nuts. I have the code which sets the display of a certain class to none. However I want to do this with several other divs which all have this class. All I want is that when I click any div with this class, that individual div disappears. Apologies for bad readability.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="section">

    <div class="bontainer">

        <div class="tbclicked clickone">
            <h1 class="one">1</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="tbclicked clicktwo">
            <h1 class="two">2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tbclicked clickthree">
            <h1 class="three">3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tbclicked clickfour">
            <h1 class="four">4</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tbclicked clickfive">
            <h1 class="five">5</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tbclicked clicksix">
            <h1 class="six">6</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tbclicked clickseven">
            <h1 class="seven">7</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tbclicked clickeight">
            <h1 class="eight">8</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tbclicked clicknine">
            <h1 class="nine">9</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tbclicked clickten">
            <h1 class="ten">10</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tbclicked clickeleven">
            <h1 class="eleven">11</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tbclicked clicktwelve">
            <h1 class="twelve">12</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<body>
```

CSS:

```css
.tbclicked {
  background-color: #fff0c9;
}
```

JS:

```js
var one = document.querySelector(".clickone");
one.addEventListener("click", function () {
  one.style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: you can also assign an ID for each div and whenever the user clicked on that, you can hide it using display : none, JQuery will make it so easy.

don't use class="tbclicked clickone" user class="tbclicked" id="clickone"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop through all elements with the desired class and add a `click` event listener to each element:

```js
const tbclicked = document.querySelectorAll('.tbclicked');
tbclicked.forEach((e) => e.addEventListener('click', ()=>{ e.style.display = "none"}));
```

```css
.tbclicked {
  background-color: #fff0c9;
}
```

```html
<div class="bontainer">
    <div class="tbclicked clickone">
        <h1 class="one">1</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="tbclicked clicktwo">
        <h1 class="two">2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clickthree">
        <h1 class="three">3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clickfour">
        <h1 class="four">4</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clickfive">
        <h1 class="five">5</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clicksix">
        <h1 class="six">6</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clickseven">
        <h1 class="seven">7</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clickeight">
        <h1 class="eight">8</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clicknine">
        <h1 class="nine">9</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clickten">
        <h1 class="ten">10</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clickeleven">
        <h1 class="eleven">11</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clicktwelve">
        <h1 class="twelve">12</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or use event delegation (recommended):

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(e.target.parentElement.classList.contains("tbclicked")){
    e.target.style.display = "none";
  }
})
```

```css
.tbclicked {
  background-color: #fff0c9;
}
```

```html
<div class="bontainer">

    <div class="tbclicked clickone">
        <h1 class="one">1</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="tbclicked clicktwo">
        <h1 class="two">2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clickthree">
        <h1 class="three">3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clickfour">
        <h1 class="four">4</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clickfive">
        <h1 class="five">5</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clicksix">
        <h1 class="six">6</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clickseven">
        <h1 class="seven">7</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clickeight">
        <h1 class="eight">8</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clicknine">
        <h1 class="nine">9</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clickten">
        <h1 class="ten">10</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clickeleven">
        <h1 class="eleven">11</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tbclicked clicktwelve">
        <h1 class="twelve">12</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much, this worked great. I'm new to Stack Overflow, so I'm wondering if in future posts I should do anything differently (jsfiddle etc.)?

Comment: @fourhundredandtwenty You can try using a snippet next time. See [the blog post on it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of events [bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture) and add an event listener on the parent:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Element clicked:', e.target.className);
});
```

```html
<div class="section">

  <div class="container">

      <div class="tbclicked clickone">
          <h1 class="one">1</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="tbclicked clicktwo">
          <h1 class="two">2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tbclicked clickthree">
          <h1 class="three">3</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tbclicked clickfour">
          <h1 class="four">4</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tbclicked clickfive">
          <h1 class="five">5</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tbclicked clicksix">
          <h1 class="six">6</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tbclicked clickseven">
          <h1 class="seven">7</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tbclicked clickeight">
          <h1 class="eight">8</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tbclicked clicknine">
          <h1 class="nine">9</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tbclicked clickten">
          <h1 class="ten">10</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tbclicked clickeleven">
          <h1 class="eleven">11</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tbclicked clicktwelve">
          <h1 class="twelve">12</h1>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```